# when will Cosmos DB Client's mapping cache be refreshed?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are using Cosmos DB SDK whose version is 2.9.2. We perform Document CRUD operations. Usually, the end-to-end P95 latency is 20ms. But sometimes the latency is over 1000ms. The high latency period lasts for 10 hours to 1 day. The collection is not throttling.

We have get some background information from:
https://icm.ad.msft.net/imp/v3/incidents/details/171243015/home
https://icm.ad.msft.net/imp/v3/incidents/details/168242283/home
There are some diagnostics strings in the tickets.

We know that the client maintains a cache of the mapping of logical partition and physical replica address. This mapping may be outdated because of replicas movement or outage. So client tries to read from the second/third replica. However, this retry has significant impact on end to end latency. We also observe that the high latency/timeout can last for several hours, even days. I expect there’s some mechanism of refreshing mapping cache in the client. But it seems the client stops visiting more than one replica only after we redeploy our service.
Here are my questions:

1. How can the client tell whether it’s unable to connect to a certain replica? Will the client wait until timeout or server tells client that the replica is unavailable?
2. In which condition the mapping cache will be refreshed? We are using Session consistency and TCP mode.
3. Will restarting our service force the cache to be refreshed? Or refreshing only happens when the machine restarts?
4. When we find there’s replica outage, is there any way to quickly mitigate?

Answer (score 0):

What operations are performed (Document CRUD or query)? 
And what are the observed latencies & frequencies? Also please check if the collection is throttling (with custom throttling policy).

Client do manage the some metada and does handle its staleness efficiently with-in SLA bounds.

Can you please create a support ticket with account details and '[RequestDiagnostis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.resourceresponsebase.requestdiagnosticsstring?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_ResourceResponseBase_RequestDiagnosticsString)' and we shall look into it.

Comment: Hi Kiran, I added some extra information in the description. You can refer to the ticket link. We do understand what happens on server side. We just want to get more knowledge of the cache refreshing mechanism in the SDK.